# I can't understand the last line. What does the speaker want to say?

Tags: grammaticality, spoken-english, parts-of-speech

Graphic designers use a variety of design element to achieve artistic or decorative effects in print or electronic mediums to ***help determine the message, and the design should convey.***

Shouldn't it be:

***Help determine the message that the design should convey?***

[image: source]

Comment: It looks like a mistake.  You ***must*** specify the source of any text you quote.  There are other mistakes in the quoted text.

Comment: I added the source

Comment: It's a trancript,  what do you expect?

Comment: I clearly heard she said "and the design should convey".

Comment: Well then, it is an error in the spoken English.  That's very common.  You can't go back and edit words as you speak them.

Answer (score 2):

This is a mistake.

Note the source is a "transcript" of some video.  That means someone has typed words quickly from spoken English, probably without much checking. Or an AI has been used, which is worse.

There will be lots of mistakes.  There are at least two here (the other one is that "element" should be "elements".